# set up Date with Calendar or DateTime

Tags: java, java-8, date

I want to set the hour and the minute of a date-instance. I have 3 solutions.

Which should I take and why? :

version 1:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 30);

return calendar.getTime();
```

version 2:

```
ZonedDateTime i = date.toInstant()
.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
.withHour(8)
.withMinute(30);

return Date.from(i.toInstant());
```

version 3:

```
ZonedDateTime i = date.toInstant()
.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
.withHour(8)
.withMinute(30);

return new Date(i.toEpochSecond());
```

Comment: It doesn't help that your first version tries to set the hour to 30, and your second and third versions do nothing about the seconds or milliseconds...

Comment: I would say version 2. It makes least use of legacy API's.

Comment: Even if you correct it...you can go which any method

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Not setting "seconds" or "milliseconds" should defaults to "0" for all 3 versions. Or?

Comment: @nimo23: What makes you think that? Which method call would you expect to affect those units? (It doesn't - I've just tested. I wouldn't expect it to, either.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Oh you are right, I need to set it explicity: ZonedDateTime i = d.toInstant()
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .withHour(hour)
    .withMinute(minute)
    .withSecond(0)
    .withNano(0);

Comment: @nimo Use version 3  for more additional information about time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version 1 is using the long outdated `Calendar` class. Another problem with it is that it is using the JVM’s current time zone setting without being explicit about this in the code, a trait that could give someone an unpleasant surprise some time in the future.

Version 2 is exploiting the newer classes as far as possible, and it is explicit about using the JVM’s time zone setting. The good solution.

Version 3 has the benefits of version 2 too, but a conversion to milliseconds since the epoch before converting to `Date`. The conversion via `Instant` in version 2 is more natural and therefore slightly preferred.

As has been mentioned in the comments, versions 2 and 3 as written in the question do not get rid of seconds and fraction of second. The simple solution (given that you want this) is to use `truncatedTo()`:

```
    ZonedDateTime i = date.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .withHour(8)
            .withMinute(30)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Best of all of course if you could avoid using the also outdated `Date` class altogether.

Comment: awesome. i didnt even know about truncatedTo :D

Answer (score -2):

if i pick version 1

ZonedDateTime is new api  i not commonly used

Comment: That sort of reasoning would stop the *vastly* superior java.time API from *ever* being used. `java.util.Calendar` should be avoided wherever possible - as should `java.util.Date`, frankly. The old Java date/time APIs were dreadful; java.time is pretty nice.